# How i can read all data in this response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this JSON object

```
{
  "0": {
    "id": "44",
    "date": "2016-06-24 10:53:08",
    "client_id": "44",
    "status": "waiting",
    "price": null,
    "paid": null,
    "client": false,
    "items": {
      "beirut": {
        "52": {
          "id": "52",
          "type": "Kerosene",
          "quantity": "50",
          "price": "20100",
          "address": "beirut"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "id": "42",
    "date": "2016-06-24 10:43:35",
    "client_id": "44",
    "status": "waiting",
    "price": null,
    "paid": null,
    "client": false,
    "items": {
      "beirut": {
        "50": {
          "id": "50",
          "type": "Super 98",
          "quantity": "60",
          "price": "34900",
          "address": "beirut"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "status": "ok"
}
```

I want to **read** all data from that response in **javascript**.

This is returned in a `jquery.ajax` call as `datatype:jsonp`. I am able to access **data** and that displays all the stores in html page.

**How can I read this properly?**

Comment: What is your main issue in reading those data?

Comment: if it's JSONP the response need to include callback function like `callback({...})`, right now it's not JSONP but just JSON.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Right now we do not fully see a problem.

Comment: i want to read the `status` ,the `items` from this Object

Comment: `for (var obj in data) {
  if (data[obj].id && data[obj].status) {
    console.log(data[obj].id,data[obj].status)
  }  
}` https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/5kgkuvn2/

Comment: @mplungjan 10x for your response , but how i can read the `id` from the `items` obj ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sqhhyL8h/

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Code goes here

var obj = {
  "0": {
    "id": "44",
    "date": "2016-06-24 10:53:08",
    "client_id": "44",
    "status": "waiting",
    "price": null,
    "paid": null,
    "client": false,
    "items": {
      "beirut": {
        "52": {
          "id": "52",
          "type": "Kerosene",
          "quantity": "50",
          "price": "20100",
          "address": "beirut"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "1": {
    "id": "42",
    "date": "2016-06-24 10:43:35",
    "client_id": "44",
    "status": "waiting",
    "price": null,
    "paid": null,
    "client": false,
    "items": {
      "beirut": {
        "50": {
          "id": "50",
          "type": "Super 98",
          "quantity": "60",
          "price": "34900",
          "address": "beirut"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "status": "ok"
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
  
 if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
   console.log(key,obj[key]);
 }
})
```